# Rails: Cache multiple result sets during a session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord, memcached

I have a Rails app that searches a static set of documents, and I need to figure out the best way to cache result sets.  I can't just use the native ActiveRecord caching.

**My situation:**

I'm using the will_paginate gem, and at the moment, the query is running every time the user changes pages.  Some queries are too complex for this to be responsive, so I need to cache the results, at least during an individual session.  Also, the user may have multiple tabs open, running separate queries simultaneously.  The document set is static; the size of the set is on the order of tens of thousands of documents.

**Why straight-forward ActiveRecord caching won't work:**

The user can search the contents of the documents, or search based on metadata restrictions (like a date range), or both.  The metadata for each document is stored in an ActiveRecord, so those criteria are applied with an ActiveRecord query.

But if they add a search term for the document content, I run that search using a separate FastCGI application, because I'm doing some specialized search logic.  So, I pass the term & the winnowed-down document list to the FastCGI application, which responds with the final result list.  Then I do another ActiveRecord query: where("id IN (?)',returnedIds)

By the way, it's these FastCGI searches that are sometimes complex enough to be unresponsive.

**My thoughts:**

There's the obvious-to-a-newbie approach: I can use the metadata restrictions plus the search term as a key; they're already stored in a hash.  They'd be paired up with the returnedIds array.  And [this guide at RubyOnRails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores) mentions the cache stores that are available.  But it's not clear to me which store is best, and I'm also assuming there's a gem that's better for this.

I found the gem memcached, but it's not clear to me whether it would work for caching the results of my FastCGI request.